# Ubuntu 18.04 SD card stopped being recognized on ONE account only

Tags: drivers, usb, mount, configuration, sd-card

I was working in Cura and the SD card was mounted. I had a Cura save dialog box open and it showed the mounted SD so from that dialog box I unmounted the SD card.  I then cancelled the dialog box when I realized I was in it.

After that, in this one user account only, SD cards are not recognized. The SD does not show with lsusb.

Interestingly enough, if I log out of that account and log back into a different user account, I can insert the same SD card and lsusb shows it and it is detected and mounted.

So its definitely something in that one account. But I don't know what to look for.

I have rebooted the computer several times.

Comment: You could check if it appears in the Disks program.

Comment: Yes, I checked that and it didn't.  However it in-explicable started working again.

Answer (score 0):

After using the other working account, I looked at the modified dates on files in the account.  The 2 files that seemed the most relevant where .ICEauthority and .config/.dconf/user.  While in the other account I su'd into my account and renamed these two files.

Upon logging into my account again, the first time I tried the SD, nothing happened again. But after a while I tried it again and it is now working.

I can't say that anything I did fixed it.  Would sure like to understand what happened.